# how to store results of jira.search_issues in DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am using jira.search_issues to get all the issues in a project and now to print status of each issue I have to loop through return object. Instead I want to store all of them in a DataFrame. Is this possible? If yes, How?

Answer (score 1):

While you're probably looking for something less brute force you can definitely iterate through the ResultList of issues and extract them into a dict of dicts (or lists or tuples), which you can then read into your dataframe. See https://towardsdatascience.com/communication-story-from-an-issue-tracking-software-efbbf29736ff for one such approach.